# How to save a resource from .resx to hard drive?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, resx

I have a Windows Forms project with the standard `main.resx` file where a `.ecfg` file is saved (configuration file).

How can I extract this file to the hard drive?

Comment: it´s a winforms program which contains a (e.g.) ascii text file which i want to save to (e.g.) C:\mytext.txt. The file could also be an executable which has to be temporary placed in the file system, e.g. an updater which is a seperate process to delete the normal executable or something else.

Comment: The point is: I load a file into the resx-file via the designer and at runtime i want to programmatically extract it to the hard drive.

Comment: Maybe this [MSDN-Entry][msdn1] could help you. [msdn1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ekyft91f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the namespace on your resource file.  Usually they are put into the Properties namesapce.  You can then access the file like this:

```
byte[] b = Properties.Main.Something;    //Something being the name of the resource
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\yourfile.ecfg", b);
```